# How to write a recursive rule for this number sequence: 3,5,14,69,965,66584

Tags: sequences-and-series

3 and 5 is the closest number to each other with a difference of 2. The other numbers are very far apart.

Comment: This is sequence A055937 in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A055937

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n$ be the sequence. $$a_1=3, a_2=5\\ a_n = a_{n-1}a_{n-2}-1,\forall n>2$$